# Array Sorting Issues in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am trying to make a program that sorts an array without using the sort function (that won't work with objects or structs). I have made the greater than one work, but the less than one keeps changing the greatest element in the array to a one and sorting it wrong, and when used with the greater than function, the first element is turned into a large number. Can someone please help me fix this or is it my compiler.

```
void min_sort(int array[], const unsigned int size){
    for(int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if(array[i] > array[i+1]){
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i+1];
                array[i+1] = temp;
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: When `i==size-1` (the last time your loop runs), then `i+1` is out of bounds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looping correctly. Looks like you are trying `bubble sort` which is:

```
void min_sort(int array[], const unsigned int size){
    for(int k = 0; k < size; k++)
        for(int i = k+1; i < size; i++)
            if(array[i] < array[k]){
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[k];
                array[k] = temp;
            }
}
```

Comment: That's not bubble sort ... That's closer to a selection sort, but doing a lot of unneeded swaps.

Comment: Maybe, I could not tell since it looks like both, but was closer to bubble sort.

Comment: OP's was a bubble sort, yours is a strange selection sort.

Answer (score 1):

```
void min_sort(int array[], const unsigned int size)
{
  for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<size-1-i;j++)
    {
      if(array[j]>array[j+1])
      {
        swap(array[j] , array[j+1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I see that you are trying to implement the `bubble sort` algorithm. I have posted the code for bubble sort here. In bubble sort you basically compare the element at an `index j` and the element next to it at index `j+1`. If `array[j]` is greater than `array[j+1]` , you swap them using the `swap()` function or by using the `temp` method. The outer loop will run `size - 1` times  , and the inner loop will run `size - 1 - i` times because the last element will already be in place.

For Example we have an array of size 4 with elements such as :

`array[i] = [100,90,8,10]`

The bubble sort will sort it in the following steps :

`90,100,8,10`
`90,8,100,10`
`90,8,10,100`

`8,90,10,100`
`8,10,90,100`

`8,10,90,100`

See, the use of `size-1-i` . You can see the nested loop runs less number of times in each iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one mistake that your 2nd loop condition should be:  `i < size -1`.

So it should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size -1; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt at bubble sort is basically correct, you just have an out of bounds issue with your inner loop. During the inner loop's last run, `i == size - 1`, therefore `i + 1` is equal to `size`, thus `data[i+1]` is out of range. Simply change the condition of your `for` to be `i < size - 1`.

Working example: https://godbolt.org/z/e5ohWPfTz